# Trapz matlab function in Java

Tags: java, matlab

I'm building a Java program translating some matlab operation.

In matlab there is this function:

```
aVLF=trapz(F(iVLF),PSD(iVLF));
```

now I should to do the same function in Java. There is a library that implement this function ?

Comment: The [Trapezoidal Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) (or Trapezium Rule) should be pretty easy to implement from scratch - have you tried? Asking for off-site recommendations is off topic here.

Comment: No I don't know this trapezoidal formula

Comment: That's not what I asked, I asked if you'd *tried*, because the formula (which I linked to) is relatively simple, it's just prescribed addition of your input elements